# why do they want to save a hash in an array?

Tags: perl

I saw a very strange piece of code in a perl script used in my project, it's something like:

```
my $arrayRef = [
    A => {AA => 11, AAA => 111},
    B => {BB => 11, BBB => 111},
];
```

IMO, it tries to construct an anonymous array from a hash table. I try to print the array element and here is what I get:

```
foreach (@$arrayRef )
{
    print;
    print "\n";
}

A
HASH(0x1e60220)
B
HASH(0x1e71bd0)
```

which means it treats every element (key&value) in the hash table as a separate element in the anonymous array. However I am really confused about why do they want to save a hash into an array. The **ONLY** benefit for me is to save some memory if the hash table is really huge. Is this a wedely used perl tricks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> it tries to construct an anonymous array from a hash table.

No, it constructs an anonymous array from a four-element *list*.

```
A => {AA => 11, AAA => 111}, B => {BB => 11, BBB => 111}
```

is exactly the same thing as

```
'A', {AA => 11, AAA => 111}, 'B', {BB => 11, BBB => 111}
```

---

The use of `=>` does imply some sort of relationship, so I suppose they could have used

```
{ A => {AA => 11, AAA => 111}, B => {BB => 11, BBB => 111} }
```

or

```
[ [ A => {AA => 11, AAA => 111} ], [ B => {BB => 11, BBB => 111} ] ]
```

or any of a million other data structures, but there's way to know why one was chosen over another from what you gave.

Comment: it's really my first time to see **=>** can be used as list separator. It means I can construct an array in this way: 
`my $arrayRef = [A=>B=>C=>D=>E=>F]`

is this mean any other characters can also be used as list separator? 

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need a `=>` after the `F` or you'd need to quote the `F`, but yeah. // I'm not sure I understand your second question. It sounds like you're asking if `1+2+3+4+5` is the same thing as `1,2,3,4,5`, but it's obviously not.

Comment: I just checked perl reference, and found that => and comma are actually the same thing. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Not quite the same thing. `=>` autoquotes it's LHS.

Answer (score 2):

It's an anonymous array, in which alternates a string key with an anonymous hash. The answer to your question: it depends on context, a concrete data-structure should help to resolve a concrete problem. So if we have only the data-structure and forget the problem we are trying to resolve, it's harder to imagine why they used this construction.

Perhaps, they needed a "ordered hash of hashes", the array structure makes sure the order, hash not